# Is this ILP NP-hard?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, np-hard

I formalized a problem and finished with this ILP:
[image: http://s14.postimg.org/snuhla2s1/Screenshot_from_2013_08_20_15_47_35.png]

I have tried to reduce to multiple Knapsack problem to prove it is NP-hard but I was stuck because of the constraint (4).
Could someone give me some suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: N(r,s) = (s1,s2, ...) is set fo neighbour for (r,s). I know prior